# How to install GearmanManager on Amazon AMI EC2 Micro Instance?

Tags: php, linux, installation, amazon-ec2, gearman

I believe amazon's linux is CentOS/RHEL based but I cannot install GearmanManager on the server.

How do I go about doing this?

```
[root@ip-10-100-100-10 install]$ ./install.sh
Detecting linux distro as redhat- or debian-compatible
Only Redhat Enterprise (RHEL) or Debian systems currently supported
[root@ip-10-100-100-10 install]$
```

`cat /etc/issue` outputs `Amazon Linux AMI release 2011.02.1.1 (beta)`

Comment: The OS EC2 uses is based completely on which AMI you choose.  Honestly, you can run pretty much any linux distro you please on EC2.  So pick a compatible AMI when you launch your instance.

Comment: I am using the default Amazon Linux the one in the free tier for testing purposes

Comment: what is result of `cat /etc/issue`?

Comment: @Aivan Monceller You could choose Debian AMI from alestic (& others) - http://thecloudmarket.com/owner/063491364108--alestic-com-eric-hammond-

Comment: To resolve this I created a CentOS instance :|

Comment: @Aivan Monceller it will be good to work with Debian, they have stable packages and when it install it does a thorough check-up of dependencies installs them if found missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this I opted for another Linux instance

Comment: what AMI did you end up using?

Answer (score 4):

I actually started using the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repositories for specific things that are not normally in RHEL or Amazon Linux Repos. You can go to the [EPEL FAQs](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#How_can_I_install_the_packages_from_the_EPEL_software_repository.3F) and find out the specifics on installing `EL6`, which allows you to install gearman on Amazon Linux AMI as an rpm without losing support of AWS Toolkits.

After you gave the latest version installed you will then run:

```
yum --enablerepo=epel install gearmand
```

The only software that will be installed from that repo is `gearmand` and `libgearman`.

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest solution. Thanks.